# Fast numpy operation on part of dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe with several columns. 2 of them are date and time and others are numerical.

I need to perform fast in-place calculation on the numerical part of the dataframe. Currently I ignore first 2 columns and convert numericals to a numpy and use it further down the code as a numpy.

However I want to keep these processed numericals in the dataframe without touching date and time.

Now:

```
# tanh norm
def tanh_ret():
    data = df.to_numpy()
    mu = np.mean(data)
    std = np.std(data)
    return 0.5 * (np.tanh(0.01 * ((data - mu) / std)) + 1)

del df['Date']
del df['Time']
nums = tanh_ret()
del df
```

What I want: normalize 3 df columns out of 5 **in-place**

Mind that the dataset is large so I would prefer as less data copy as possible but also reasonably fast.

Comment: you can use **.apply** method with a map (*a dict* for example) to specify which column has to be processed

Comment: sounds good. can you write an answer?

Comment: `apply` will perhaps slow down things but you can select numerics and do computation `nums = df.select_dtypes("number"); df[nums.columns] = np.tanh(nums.sub(nums.mean()).div(nums.std()).mul(0.01)).add(1).mul(0.5)`. Not sure what exactly you meant by in-place

Comment: in-place has very simple meaning - without copying data into separate data structure. ie not duplicating RAM usage.. regarding `select_dtypes` - how do I place the numbers back into the original dataframe?

Comment: that code does that

Comment: write it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Create a random pandas dataframe

I consider 5 columns of random values, you can place what you want. The *Time* and *Date* columns are set to a constant value.

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((100,5)))
now = dt.datetime.now()

df['Time'] = now.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
df['Date'] = now.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

### Inplace numerical processing

```
def tanh_ret(data):
    mu = data.mean()
    std = data.std()
    return 0.5 * (np.tanh(0.01 * ((data - mu) / std)) + 1)

num_cols =df.columns[df.dtypes != 'object']
df[num_cols] = df[num_cols].transform(tanh_ret)
```

Alternatively:

```
tan_map = {col: tanh_ret for col in num_cols}
df[num_cols] = df.transform(tan_map)
```

[Source](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html#pandas.DataFrame.transform)